# Is there a way to display SCALD image and have it link to outside website: Drupal 7

Tags: scald

I have created a content type that uses a SCALD atom image field.  When that content type is displayed on my site, I want the image to link to an outside website if it is clicked upon.  I don't want to use a view to make this action happen.

I can easily add a URL field to my SCALD Image atom, but I don't know how to make this link work when the image is clicked on ONLY in the full node view.

Could someone suggest a solution?

Comment: As I don't know if you're looking for a D7 or a D8 solution (you could tag your Q with just '7' or '8'), and do not know if your SCALD image field is a default image field, i just recommend the following module which enables you to create a view mode where the URL field can be mapped to an image: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter.

Comment: sorry - I put Drupal 7 in the header. As to that module, I believe I gave it a try before and it did not work with SCALD - I'll look at it again.  Also, I do not want to use a view to make this work - is that what you meant by view mode?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see you have managed this. The "view mode" term does not refer to views but instead to the different modes a node can be viewed (e.g. "teaser" or "full content"). These view modes can be extended to meet other requirements. You can manage a content types view modes under admin/structure/types/manage/name-of-your-content-type/display

Comment: thanks for the clarification - I'm always working to get the terminology right.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the module Image Link Formatter a try, but I could not get it to work and I filed this bug report: https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter/issues/2970937

Instead I used the Linked Field module:https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field plus Token: https://www.drupal.org/project/token.

To make this work, I have a content type that uses a SCALD Atom for the image field and I have a separate field to add a URL.  Under the **Manage Display tab** for your content type, go to the **Link to Content** section (click on the gear wheel) and opt to **Link this Field**. You will be presented with a **Destination** field.

You'll need to browse the available tokens to find the destination field that pertains to your content type.  Make sure to use the one with dashes instead of underscores and in the case of a URL, you'll need to append the token with **:url**.  Mine looked like this:

[node:field-default-content-link-url:**url**]

If the field on my content type is populated, it links to the website.  If it is empty, the image is not formatted as a link.